# Configure Netty server to receive HTTP response

Tags: netty

I have a netty server that is set up to receive http requests and send http responses. However,  the server is not able to receive http responses.

Initially I had the following 2 handlers in the pipeline and it worked fine as a regular server.

org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseEncoder

To receive responses I added the

org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseDecoder

to the pipeline. But that did not help.

How do I need to configure the server so that I am able to receive http responses?

Comment: Are you trying to write an http server or client?

Comment: It is more like a relay server. I need it to both accept and send responses.

Answer (score 1):

guess u want to make a proxy!

Use a different pipeline and ClientBootstrap to forward messages and add the two handlers:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
```

HTH